# datepicker not working using jquery

Tags: jquery

in the below code when I am clicking date field it not showing anything. can any one help me from this issue?

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/base/all.css">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="ui/core.js"></script>
<script src="ui/widget.js"></script>
<script src="ui/datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demos.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: did u check console? got any error ?

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper for chrome browser Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function giving this error

Comment: datepicker is undefined ?

Comment: Hi friends I got the solution just I removed one js file now it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you..May be your'e `ui jquery` is not including properly.Use below code

**External Links**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Script Here**

```
 <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
      </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```